# Android Studio Build Gradle Not Found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an Android Studio Project, This is the `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = "1.1.3"
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
}
```

}

When i try to build the application i get this error:

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not find gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0).
Searched in the following locations:
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.jar
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (899 ms)
```

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Your answer help me fix this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Gradle sync failed: Could not find gradle.jar
>   (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0).

You should upgrade **`tools.build:gradle`** version.

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
 classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.31"
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
```

And **`gradle-wrapper`** will

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip //5.4.1
```

After that, **`Clean->Rebuild-> Gradle`**

Comment: It's necessary to upgrade the build Gradle to this version? and the google-services also? Because I'm afraid it will make a lot of changes in my project

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the gradle-wrapper.properties file to latest distribution url.
Find all available versions
[here](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)